# Why doesnt my 's' key work in the Python repl?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I am experiencing a very frustrating problem when trying to work in the REPL.  For some reason, the "s" key does not work, so I can only type commands that use the other 25 letters of the alphabet.

I have tried this with at least three or four different versions of Python, and always the same result.  I can type my "s" at the command line, and of course I can run my code from a file, but within the REPL I have to be "s"-less.

I have checked my readline config to make sure there is nothing funky going on there, but I don't know what else could be happening.

Comment: As in the actual, normal REPL you get by running `python` from the command line, or some sort of IDE thing?

Comment: Does anything change if you run `python -S` instead of `python`? What about `python -I -S`?

Comment: Which operating system and terminal emulator are you using? If you run python on a terminal outside X, do you see the same problem? If you start an on-screen keyboard display which shows which keys are pressed, are there any modifier keys (like `Ctrl` or `Meta`) that are shown as being pressed?

Comment: I am using OpenSUSE Leap 42.3.  The problem happens for every version of Python I try to run, and same result whether started in a terminal emulator (Qterm) or a virtual console (Ctrl-Alt-F1).

Comment: If I start with `python -S` I get my `s` key back.  Same with `python -I`, except now I cannot exit with `exit()`.  Using both flags together, `python -I -S` doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Can you give a brief summary of what these options do?  I am having trouble following the `man` page, and `-I` isn't even documented here.

Comment: And more importantly, how can I change the default behaviour so I can start the REPL without a flag and still have access to my `s` key?